# Apply STDistance to all rows of table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, geolocation

I'm trying to return all the rows from `[store]` with distance of less than 10 miles. Table `[Store]` has a column of type `Geography`.

I understand how to find the distance between two specific points, something like this:

```
declare @origin geography
select @origin = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(-73.935242 AS 
VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(40.730610 AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326)

declare @destination geography
select @destination = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(-93.732666 AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(30.274096 AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326)

select @origin.STDistance(@destination)/ 1609.344 as 'distance in miles'
```

I'm having trouble applying this logic to a `SELECT` statement. Instead of getting the distance between `@origin` and `@destination`, I would like to get the distance in miles between `@origin` and `store.Geolocation` for all rows.

Comment: A SWAG would be `select * from Store where @origin.STDistance( Store.Geolocation ) / 1609.344 < 10.0`. What have you tried?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. It worked.

Comment: If you want, post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

The [`STDistance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stdistance-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) method, used from one instance of `Geography` and applied to another, returns the distance between the two points. It can be used with variables, e.g. `@Origin.STDistance( @Destination )`, columns or a combination thereof, e.g. to find all of the stores within 10 miles of a particular `@Origin`:

```
select *
  from Store
  where @Origin.STDistance( Store.Geolocation ) < 1609.344 * 10.0;
```

Note: As BenThul pointed out, spatial index handling is a bit fickle. An `STDistance` compared to a constant is SARGable: `@Origin.STDistance( Store.Geolocation ) < 1609.344 * 10.0`, but this mathematically equivalent expression is not: `@Origin.STDistance( Store.Geolocation ) / 1609.344 < 10.0`. This "feature" is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-2017#methods).

Comment: As written, that where clause isn't SARGable. That is, it will have to evaluate every row to see whether it matches. Instead, move the math to one side of the comparison. Like `@Origin.STDistance( Store.Geolocation ) < 10.0 * 1609.344`.

Comment: @BenThul One would hope that the query optimizer would do the right thing, but one's hopes would be dashed. Your assertion is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-2017#methods). Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Indeed. At this point, I'd advocate for an edit on your answer to incorporate your new understanding so that folks coming to this answer in the future are on the virtuous path.